Erro: String or binary data would be truncated SQL SERVER, mas a coluna de destino tem espaço sobrando
Tenho uma procedure que limpo uma tabela com delete e na sequencia faço um insert com select ex:
INSERT INTO TABELA1 (nm_nome) 
     SELECT stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + rtrim(nm_nome) 
       FROM GERENTE
      WHERE cd_gerente in (1,2,4,9)
            FOR XML path('')), 1, 1, '')

Meu problema é que estou recebendo a mensagem "Msg 8152, Nível 16, Estado 30, Procedimento dbo.sp_ImportaGerente, Linha 13 [Linha de Início do Lote 10]
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.", mas minha coluna "nm_nome" é um varchar(1000) e o maior retorno dela tem 64 caracteres, já tentei implementar nvarchar(max), substring(stuff(...),1,100), converter para varchar(100) mas não obtive sucesso.
Resolvi então criar um cursor com os dados para ver se encontrava algum registro em especifico que apresentasse o erro, mas para minha surpresa o cursor funcionou e preencheu todos os gerentes na mesma tabela.
Ai fica minha dúvida, insert com select tem alguma limitação relacionada a stuff ou talvez pelo modo em que uso meu stuff com FOR XML path('')? Como posso contornar isto? Pois meu cursor demora 3x mais para realizar o preenchimento da mesma tabela do que se eu fizer um insert com select.

olá Gabriel. Para testar que está tudo bem a sua tabela de destino "TABELA1", tente pegar o resultado apenas do select e inserir diretamente um valor de retorno grande pra ver o resultado. Uma pergunta, vc tem triggers associadas à TABELA1 ?

Essa query não está tentando inserir uma única linha, com os dados de todos os gerentes concatenados? É essa concatenação que deve estar ultrapassando o limite da coluna.
